# Django Social Auth issue with Coinbase

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, django-2.0

Im using `https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django`
to make it easy to add new oauths to my django app.

I have added it to my settings files and filled in the keys.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
]
```

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_COINBASE_KEY = os.environ.get('COINBASE_ID')
SOCIAL_AUTH_COINBASE_SECRET = os.environ.get('COINBASE_SECRET')

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.coinbase.CoinbaseOAuth2',  # for Coinbase authentication
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <- Here
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <- Here
            ],
        },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'user.apps.UserConfig',     
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    'social_django',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

However when I see the oauth screen of coinbase, I press next, I get redirected to my redirect uri,

Then it gives me an error

```
HTTPError at /auth/complete/coinbase/
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user
```

I have been trying to fix this issue for hours now but I cant seem to find anything on this